# How to test if X-UA-Compatible is served?

Tags: http-headers, ie8-compatibility-mode

How can I test if `<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">` does work? Especially if I let Apache handle it via htaccess.

Is there something in the IE developer tools?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check it in IE8. If it is not set, Tools > Compatibility View will be usable. If it is set, the option will be grayed out and not usable.

Comment: ah ok now i got what exactly this setting does. It's two in one. The thing is that setting it in the meta tag does not work (don't know why) and that was the reason i did not see a difference. The other problem is that it was not working in the htaccess and was allways giving a 500 error. I figured out now that the htaccess setting works if i don't set "env=ie" at the and of "Header set X-UA-Compatible "IE=Edge,chrome=1". What does this "env=ie" normaly do, cause its not working on my webhost?

Comment: The last sentence of this answer should read:  "If it IS set, the option will be grayed out and not usable."

Comment: Thanks @BenjaminRay! Fixed :-)

Answer (score 1):

check the "page default" of document mode, from IE developer tool bar.

Answer (score 0):

Do you see the "broken" document icon between search and reload icons in the image? This is the Compatibility View button. If the `edge` value set using the meta tag or htaccess header worked, the Compatibility View button is not shown.

[image]

Image courtesy of [Frank Code blog](http://frankcode.wordpress.com/2013/10/17/a-guide-to-ie-compatibility-view-and-x-ua-compatible/); you may also have a read at the post, if you want. It's worth it.